# ProgressBar с постоянно меняющимся цветом. Android

Tags: android, color, progress-bar

Создать вертикальный ProgressBar в котором цвет постепенно переходит от голубого в красный.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android